# Handling EnvironmentObject in a multiple window/tab setting

Tags: swift, swiftui

How is the best way to provide a different `EnvironmentObject` (or a substitution) for a multiple tab/window setting?

Let's say we have following `MultipleWindow` view:

```
struct MultipleWindow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var environmentObject: EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            ForEach(environmentObject.selectedPhoneSize.indices) { index in
                Button("Select \(environmentObject.selectedPhoneSize[index].size)") {
                    environmentObject.selectedPhoneSize[environmentObject.selectedSizeIndex()].selected = false
                    environmentObject.selectedPhoneSize[index].selected = true
                
                }
                
            }
            
            ForEach(environmentObject.phones) { phone in
                if phone.size == environmentObject.selectedPhoneSize[environmentObject.selectedSizeIndex()].size {
                    Text("\(phone.model): \(phone.price)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And EnvironmentObject:

```
class EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPhoneSize = phoneSizes
    @Published var phones = phoneArray
    
    func selectedSizeIndex() -> Int {
        return
            selectedPhoneSize.firstIndex {
                $0.selected == true
            } ?? 0
    }
    
}

struct PhoneSize: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var size: String
    var selected: Bool
}

let phoneSizes = [
    PhoneSize(size: "M", selected: true),
    PhoneSize(size: "X", selected: false),
    PhoneSize(size: "L", selected: false),
]

struct Phone: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var size: String
    var model: String
    var price: Int
}

let phoneArray = [
    Phone(size: "L", model: "New", price: 500),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "Old", price: 400),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "New", price: 600),
    Phone(size: "M", model: "New", price: 650)
]
```

and AppDelegate:

```
@main
struct Testing_appApp: App {
    @StateObject var environmentObject = EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MultipleWindow().environmentObject(environmentObject)
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected - you first choose a model size and then see filtered results from `ForEach`. The issue is that when you open additional window (i.e. in iPad or macOS), any selection you make will be made in all the windows. I use `EnvironmentObject` because I use it throughout the app. The same I use i.e. for tag-selection so I could change the current view from any view without any issue. Is there a way to keep all the benefits of `EnvironemntObject` and present a different `EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow` for each window or tab?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object in place

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MultipleWindow()
          .environmentObject(EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow())  // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it unfortunately doesn't work as I still get the same environmentObject somehow (tested on both iPad and Mac)

Answer (score 0):

What @Asperi said is true but your problem is that in the `MultipleWindow` you're using the
`@EnvironmentObject var environmentObject: EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow`.

The only solution i see right now is:

1. in `MultipleWindow` in the init method pass a `EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow`
2. If you have multiple `MultipleWindow`s you can

```
MultipleWindow(<EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow taken from environment>)
or
MultipleWindow(EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow())
```

and in

```
struct MultipleWindow: View {
    private var environmentObjectMultipleWindow: EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow;

    init(environmentObjectMultipleWindow: EnvironmentObjectMultipleWindow) {
     self.environmentObjectMultipleWindow = environmentObjectMultipleWindow
    }
```